# Where does iPhoto'11 store its photos?

Tags: photos.app, macos

Does it work like Aperture and store files in its own directory? If so, where is this?  I'm debating on dropping Aperture to save space on my hard drive, so want to know how iPhoto works before I switch.

Thanks

Comment: My experience is that iPhone has more trouble in saving space than Aperture. Aperture can work with multiple collections more easily than iPhoto. I switched from iPhoto to Aperture for the same reason, space. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iPhoto stores its Library in your User-Directory.

The Path: ~/Pictures/

Right-Click on the Package, and then select "Show Package Contnet" to view your pictures!

Or, right-Click on a picture in iPhoto, and select "Show in Finder"

Comment: Regarding access through iPhoto, I have no "Show in Finder" for the one photo I imported into iPhoto when I right-click. This is on iPhoto'11.  Regarding the library, I see it now via Terminal.  Finder must hide the directory/library. Tricky Lion...tisk tisk :)

Answer (score 1):

http://support.apple.com/kb/PH2341

The above points out a setting whereby you can control where photos get stored.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 1):

MacintoshHD/Users/$YOU$/Pictures/iPhotoLibrary/Masters/$Year$/$Month$/$Date$

Have moved mine now getting to removing iPhoto. I don't categorise my life into events so it is useless to me, I can never find anything.